# How can I access an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am supposed to enter the name, number of stocks, purchase price, and current price, and then calculate the purchase total, current total, and profit. The program should then output the name, purchase total, current total, and profit.

I keep getting an error or a crash after I enter my input:

[image: Screenshot of error alert]

(Click to enlarge.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void load(char *name, float *share, float *buyprice, float *currprice)
{
    printf("Enter stock name");
    gets(name);
    printf("Enter share, buyprice, currprice");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &*share, &*buyprice, &*currprice);
}
void calc(float share, float buyprice, float currprice, float *buytotal, float *currtotal, float *profit)
{
    *buytotal = share * buyprice;
    *currtotal = share * currprice;
    *profit = *currtotal - *buytotal;
}
void output(char name, float profit, float buytotal, float currtotal)
{
    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("buy total %f\n", buytotal);
    printf("current total %f\n", currtotal);
    printf("profit %f\n", profit);

}

void main()
{
    char name [25];
    float share, buyprice, currprice, buytotal, currtotal, profit;
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(*name, buytotal, currtotal, profit);
    fflush(stdin);
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(*name, buytotal, currtotal, profit);
    fflush(stdin);
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(*name, buytotal, currtotal, profit);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You keep getting *what* error? Please  [edit] your question to be as precise as possible.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/uayeqr7ot/

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors, can you try this:

```
void load(char *name, float *share, float *buyprice, float *currprice)
{
    printf("Enter stock name");
    gets(name);
    printf("Enter share, buyprice, currprice");
    scanf("%f %f %f", share, buyprice, currprice); // changes: removed &*
}
void calc(float share, float buyprice, float currprice, float *buytotal, float *currtotal, float *profit)
{
   *buytotal = share * buyprice;
   *currtotal = share * currprice;
   *profit = *currtotal - *buytotal;
}
void output(char *name, float profit, float buytotal, float currtotal) // changes: char name to char *name
{
   printf("%s\n", name);
   printf("buy total %f\n", buytotal);
   printf("current total %f\n", currtotal);
   printf("profit %f\n", profit);
}

int main(void) //changed to int main(void)
{
    char name [25];
    float share, buyprice, currprice, buytotal, currtotal, profit;
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(name, buytotal, currtotal, profit); //changed *name to name
    fflush(stdin);
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(name, buytotal, currtotal, profit); //changed *name to name
    fflush(stdin);
    load(name, &share, &buyprice, &currprice);
    calc(share, buyprice, currprice, &buytotal, &currtotal, &profit);
    output(name, buytotal, currtotal, profit); //changed *name to name
    return 0; //Added this line
 }
```

Comment: IT WORKED! can you tell me what changes you made??